# Strings 2018 takeaways

Tags: string-theory, de-sitter-spacetime, string-theory-landscape

What are the main takeaways from the [Strings 2018 conference](https://indico.oist.jp/indico/event/5/)? What are the main announcements, discoveries or directions emerging from this event?

To my knowledge, one is the result by Vafa and others on the tension between the Swampland and de Sitter.

Disclaimer: I know that this question might be considered too much opinion based. In that case, please point me out other possible places in which question could be asked.

Comment: What is opinion-based about this question? It may be too-broad, but it is very much an objective question.

Comment: This is a good question for this forum, as I'm sure many of us were there, and where else would it be asked?